# How to get the value of data-id (inside JS) in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a link_to :

```html
<%= link_to image_tag("accept.png"), mark_payed_path(req),
 data: { id: req.id }, remote: true %>
```

And i have data-id which equals the id of the "req" variable.
I have a method mark_payed in my controller and mark_payed.js.erb file in my view folder which handles javascript functionality.

```html
$(function () {
    var rowID = $(this).data("id");   
  alert(rowID);             
});
```

When my alert call runs i get "undefined". So i dont know how to get that data-id value.

Here is what my link_to tag generates:

```html
<a data-id="6" data-remote="true" href="/requests/mark_payed/6">
   <img src="/assets/accept-c384470504c2c8cd75c0fd642323db90.png">
</a>
```

Comment: What does a console.log( $(this) ) output?

Comment: And just to make sure, what does `$(this).attr("data-id")` return?

Comment: @ForgetfulFellow It returns undefinded